# connect an asp.net page to the SQL server database(visual studio 2010)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have an asp.net page in which I have 2 textboxes named username and password and I want when I will press the login button, the **dataprovided** in text boxes should be inserted in the database table. I have created a table named admin_login and also give columns and given

```
INSERT INTO admin_login VALUES(" .........")
```

and provided a connection string in a class file still I am having a problem in inserting the data in database.

Do I need to put my connection string in another place as like in web.config file or I am doing something else wrong?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: there is no error .... but the task that i want to perform is not happening .... i.e. to insert into the table ... when i am filing the textboxes .. then that data must be shown in the dtabse ... but it is not happening ... :(

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection con= new sqlConnection("data source=server name; initial catalog=database name; integrated security=true");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO admin (username,password)VALUES('"+textbox1.text+"','"+textbox2.text+"')",con);
    cmd.commandType= commandType.text;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
```

try this code use namespace system.sqlClient;

Answer (score 0):

connection string in web-config

after that, create a class i have use this class having name ConCls, having following code

```
public SqlConnection getconnection()
{


string con = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ToString();
    SqlConnection scon = new SqlConnection(con);
    return scon;
}
```

"constr" is the name u provided to connection string

and on button clickevent

```
 cmd.Connection = new ConCls().getConnection();
        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO admin (username,password) VALUES('"+textbox1.text+"','"+textbox2.text+"')";
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteReader();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
```